# JS массив объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Я только начинаю учить JS и застряла на одном задании, прошу вашей помощи.

Задание: дан список инструкторов, нужно определить, какой инструктор имеет самое длинное имя.

```
const instructorWithLongestName = function(instructors) {
  // Put your solution here
};

console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Samuel", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Ophilia", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Donald", course: "Web"}
]);
console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Matthew", course: "Web"},
  {name: "David", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Domascus", course: "Web"}
]);
```

Вывод должен быть таким:

```
{name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web"}
{name: "Domascus", course: "Web"}
```

Решение должно быть на чистом JS без использования каких-либо библиотек.
Спасибо, тем кто отзовется и поможет.

Comment: `instructors.reduce((acc, cur)=>((acc[cur.name.length]=acc[cur.name.length]||[]).push(cur),acc),[]).pop();`

Comment: @Grundy что-то сложно. Можно проще :)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, что может быть проще цикла по поиску максимума? :)

Comment: `instructors.reduce((max, cur)=>max.name.length>cur.name.length?max:cur)` вот вроде (пишу с телефона)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я так и думал. Этот вариант не прокатит, если будет несколько элементов с максимальной длиной :-) у меня они в массив просто собираются :)

Comment: @Anna, автор ответа решил его удалить.

Comment: Ребят, тут только что был чей-то код. Я успела его скопировать и он работает! Вот только или кто-то удалил комментарий или я сама что-то нечаянно нажала( новичок еще на этом сайте.  вот этот код: 
  instructors.sort(function(a, b) { 
      return b.name.length - a.name.length;
  });
  return instructors[0].name;
};
  Спасибо) знать бы еще кому)

Comment: @Grundy ну по заданию нужно вернуть один объект. Что делать если их несколько не сказано

Comment: @AlexeyTen, меня пример вывода смутил :-) показалось что должно было вывестись два элемента, а там два вызова :)

Comment: @Anna не нужно использовать этот код. Он делает лишние ненужные действия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изначальный вариант с сортировкой (ну почти изначальный... :):

```js
const instructorWithLongestName = function(instructors) {
  return instructors.
    sort((a,b) => b.name.length - a.name.length)[0];
};

console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Samuel", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Ophilia", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Donald", course: "Web"}
]));
console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Matthew", course: "Web"},
  {name: "David", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Domascus", course: "Web"}
]));
```

То же, но с учётом вариантов, когда на входе пустой массив или количество имен с максимальной длиной более одного. Тут перебора в общем случае почти в два раза больше, чем надо, зато выглядит очень лаконично:

```js
const instructorsWithLongestName = function(instructors) {
  //Игнорируем отсутствие параметров
  if (!instructors) return [];
  
  return instructors.
    sort((a,b) => b.name.length - a.name.length).
    filter((a,b,c) => a.name.length == c[0].name.length);
};

console.log(instructorsWithLongestName([
  {name: "Samuel", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Ophilia", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Donald", course: "Web"}
]));
console.log(instructorsWithLongestName([
  {name: "Matthew", course: "Web"},
  {name: "David", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Domascus", course: "Web"}
]));
console.log(instructorsWithLongestName([]));
console.log(instructorsWithLongestName());
```

Вариант с reduce, который мне все же не нравится, так как тихо выбирает только одного из нескольких возможных с максимальной длиной имени.

```js
const instructorWithLongestName = function(instructors) {
  return instructors.reduce((longestName, instructor) => 
      longestName.name.length > instructor.name.length ? longestName : instructor
  );
};

console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Samuel", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Ophilia", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Donald", course: "Web"}
]));
console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Matthew", course: "Web"},
  {name: "David", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Domascus", course: "Web"}
]));
```

Comment: @AlexeyTen Исправил...

Comment: Хотя лучше бы простой цикл написать, а то разбираться с reduce новичкам непросто

Comment: вариант с сортировкой я поняла) спасибо. Осталось понять с reduce)

Comment: @Anna а лучше напишите свой. Нужно просто пройтись в цикле по всем инструкторам и запомнить самого длинного

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь) я воспользуюсь самым первым ответом @SergeyNudnov с вариантом сортировки, но возвращая instructors[0]; а не instructors[0].name; Этот вариант для меня самый понятный

Comment: @Anna Добавил тот изначальный вариант в более современном виде

Comment: @SergeyNudnov спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

Просто на случай если много с одинаковой длиной

```js
const instructorWithLongestName = function(instructors) {
  let result = [],
      len = 0;

  for(let i of instructors){
      if (i.name.length > len){
          len = i.name.length;
          result = [];
      }
      if (i.name.length === len){
          result.push(i);
      }
  }

  return result;
};

console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Samuel", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Ophilias", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Donald", course: "Web"}
]));
console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Matthew", course: "Web"},
  {name: "David", course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Domascus", course: "Web"}
]));
```

```js
 const instructorWithLongestName = function(instructors) {
      let maxLength = Math.max(...instructors.map(e => e.name.length));
      return instructors.filter(e => e.name.length === maxLength);
    };

    console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
      {name: "Samuel", course: "iOS"},
      {name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web"},
      {name: "Ophilias", course: "Web"},
      {name: "Donald", course: "Web"}
    ]));
    console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
      {name: "Matthew", course: "Web"},
      {name: "David", course: "iOS"},
      {name: "Domascus", course: "Web"}
    ]));
```

Comment: Брррррррр.. Сортировать массив ради выбора элемента (((

Answer (score 1):

Хотя [вариант с reduce](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/979484/178988) лучше, всё-таки предложу такой:

```js
function instructorWithLongestName(instructors) {
  var len = Math.max(...instructors.map(x => x.name.length))
  return instructors.find(x => x.name.length === len);
}

console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Samuel",   course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Jeremiah", course: "Web"},
  {name: "Ophilia",  course: "Web"},
  {name: "Donald",   course: "Web"},
]));

console.log(instructorWithLongestName([
  {name: "Matthew",  course: "Web"},
  {name: "David",    course: "iOS"},
  {name: "Domascus", course: "Web"},
]));
```

Comment: Ну почему никто не хочет написать простой цикл?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ну так напиши? Лично мне лень писать тут цикл.

Comment: С телефона только флудить удобно, а код писать не очень

Comment: @AlexeyTen, *LOL*